# Trouble starting more than one instance of Sinatra in Cucumber env.rb

Tags: ruby, sinatra, cucumber

I'm writing automation tests which are dependent on two different web services and I've decided to mock these out using two very basic Sinatra applications. However I'm having trouble starting more than one Sinatra instance in my Cucumber env file. The second Sinatra instance stops as soon as its started.

Here's a snippet of the output I get when kicking off a test

```
== Sinatra/1.4.5 has taken the stage on 9000 for development with backup from Thin
Thin web server (v1.6.2 codename Doc Brown)
Maximum connections set to 1024
Listening on localhost:9000, CTRL+C to stop

== Sinatra/1.4.5 has taken the stage on 8082 for development with backup from Thin
Thin web server (v1.6.2 codename Doc Brown)
Maximum connections set to 1024
Listening on localhost:8082, CTRL+C to stop
Stopping ...
== Sinatra has ended his set (crowd applauds)
```

As you can see the first service starts up and runs fine but the second service starts up OK but then immediately begins stopping

Sinatra app 1

```
class MockService1 < Sinatra::Base

  get '/some/endpoint' do
      response =
        {
            enabled: false
        }
  end

end
```

Sinatra app 2

```
class MockService2 < Sinatra::Base

  get '/some/endpoint' do
      response =
        {
            enabled: false
        }
  end

end
```

Inside my Cucumber env file

```
Thread.new do
  MockService1.run! host: 'localhost', port: '9000'
 end

Thread.new do
  MockService2.run! host: 'localhost', port: '8082'
 end
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to use the childprocess gem to start a new sinatra server under a new child process.

```
mock_service = ChildProcess.build('ruby', File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), 'mock_service.rb'))
mock_service.start
```